# POST A CPT IN A CAROUSEL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a dynamic carousel with CPT. My CPT works well and I added some articles but I can not display it. I am doing it this way:

```php
<section id="carousel">
    <div class="row mb-2"><!-- ROW -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Mes sites préférés</h3>
        </div>
    </div><!-- ROW -->

    <div class="row mb-5">
        <!-- CAROUSEL BOOTSTRAP -->
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'carousel',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'category_name' => 'realisations',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); 
        ?>

        <div class="col-lg-12 colCarousel">
            <div id="ExampleCarouselID" class="carousel slide shadow" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#ExampleCarouselID" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="arrowCarousel ti-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#ExampleCarouselID" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="arrowCarousel ti-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                        $thumbnail_id   = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                        $thumbnail_meta = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attatchment_image_alt', true );
                        ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php if ($the_query->current_post == 0) : ?> active"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                <a href="" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('taille-carousel', array('class' => 'img-fluid')); ?><!-- Dans functions.php -->
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="carousel-caption align-middle">
                                <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                                <a class="btnCarousel" href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url', true ); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span>Visitez le site <i class="icofont-arrow-right"></i></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.carousel-item -->
                        <!-- end second loop -->
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
            </div><!-- /.carousel-slide -->
        </div><!-- COL -->
    </div><!-- ROW -->
</section>
```

My CPT:

```php
    function cpt_carousel() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Slides', 'Post Type General Name'),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Slide', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Carousel'),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Tous les slides'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Voir les slides'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Ajouter un slide'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Ajouter un slide'),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Editer le carousel'),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Modifier le carousel'),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Rechercher un slide'),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Non trouvé'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Non trouvé dans la corbeille'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-image-flip-horizontal',
        'label'               => __( 'Sliders'),
        'description'         => __( 'Tous sur les slides'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // On fait en sorte de ne pas afficher l'éditeur etc.
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'author', 'thumbnail','custom-fields', ),
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'carousel'),

    );
    register_post_type( 'carousel', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_carousel', 0 );
```

My taxonomy:

```php
    $labels_categories = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Catégories', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Catégorie', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Rechercher une catégorie'),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Catégories populaires'),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'Toutes les Catégories'),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Editer une catégorie'),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Mettre à jour une catégorie'),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Ajouter une nouvelle catégorie'),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nom de la nouvelle catégorie'),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Séparer les Catégories avec une virgule'),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Ajouter ou supprimer un Catégorie'),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choisir parmi les plus utilisées'),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Pas de Catégories trouvés'),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Catégories'),
);

$args_categories = array(
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'labels'                => $labels_categories,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'carousel', $args_categories );
```

URL field for the carousel button:

```php
    add_action('wp_insert_post', 'champ_carousel_url');
function champ_carousel_url($postID) {
    $post = get_post($postID);
    if ($post->post_type == 'carousel') {
        add_post_meta($postID, 'url', '', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Excuse me but the formatting of the code does not work very well

CPT for the carousel:
[image]

Taxonomy:
[image]

URL field:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what CPT is and how it is related to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Excuse me but the formatting of the code does not work very well. I added the cpt to my question above.

Comment: CPT = Corel Photo Paint file?

Comment: here are the pictures

Comment: Looks like JPG to me. Please can you explain what CPT is or is supposed to be?

Comment: Bonjour, looks like you're trying to implement an image carousel on a page hosted by [WordPress on your Pi](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) using the [CPT-Bootstrap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-bootstrap-carousel/) plugin?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Formatting code blocks is very simple. Just indent it with 4 spaces or start and end the code block with a line just containing three ``` (back ticks).